# I can't use ResultActivity or similar references on my Kotlin Android App

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

Just as the title says, I can't use those references, I've tried some recommendations on updating dependencies and adding import but can't.

This is what my imports look like:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.activity.*
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract
```

This is what my dependencies look like:

```
dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.8.0-alpha06")
    implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.1")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity:1.7.2")
    implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment:1.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
}
```

To not get an 'unresolved reference' error

Comment: Which code gives you "Unresolved reference"? There's no such thing as "ResultActivity" in the androidx libraries. You have listed the `activity-ktx` library twice plus the non-ktx version in your dependencies, with different versions. You should delete all but one of the `android-ktx` ones. You should also remove the `fragment` one since it is redundant to `fragment-ktx`.